# From Security Perspective, Windows 7 with MSE is equal with Windows 8 with Windows Defender?

Tags: security, windows-7, windows-8-preview

I just install an ubuntu in my laptop, but for some reason, I need to use windows sometimes. I am wondering that I should buy a windows 7 right now or waiting for the windows 8 which would be released at October.

The only feature I care is security, from security perspective, Windows 7 with MSE is equal with Windows 8 with Windows Defender?

Comment: *windows 8 which would be released at October* Microsoft has not given a release date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not equal, but comparable. Why? Because some things will be better in Win8 and Defender than in Win7 and MSE, but at the same time you'll have loads of changed and new code in Win8 that will have less security testing than Win7 simply because of Win8 being new and different, meaning there will be new vulnerabilities specific to Win8, but not Win7.

Anyhow, I wouldn't worry too much about it. You cannot foresee everything just like you couldn't in the past. So, no reason to be more paranoid now than before. I've been using MSE quite happily on WinXP and Win7 for a few years now and I expect any upcoming Microsoft solution about the same. Your Windows box will be sufficiently secure unless you do something very unwise.